# How to view files/folders shared with me in the OneDrive windows desktop interface?

Tags: windows, onedrive, microsoft-onedrive

In the OneDrive web portal's `Shared` section I can see all files/folders that are shared with me.

In my Windows OS I have installed OneDrive and it is getting synced into `D:\OneDriveFiles` folder. I can see all my files/folders here.

This question is to ask - In the Windows desktop interface, how to view files/folders shared with me?

Answer (score -1):

This article may help you [See files shared with you in OneDrive](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/see-files-shared-with-you-in-onedrive-2c14e8e6-4e52-4c61-9778-7155d33534a1)